# SQL Ranking with multiple rows [Same users will still have same rank ]

Tags: mysql, rank

I know a little bit of SQL and I've been wondering how to select users from my `Users` table and I've found this:

```
SELECT *, FIND_IN_SET( Score, (    
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( Score ORDER BY Score DESC ) 
        FROM Users
    )
) AS Rank
FROM Users
WHERE UserID = 100
ORDER BY Score DESC
```

The problem is that if there's multiple rows of the same user, then they will get ranked individually. I was wondering how to get the highest `Score` and have `Rank` return that

What it looks like(without the `WHERE UserID = 100` clause):

```
ID-----UserID-----Score----Rank
1------100--------6--------1
2------192--------4--------2
3------192--------3--------3
```

What I want(without the `WHERE UserID = 100` clause):

```
ID-----UserID-----Score----Rank
1------100--------6--------1
2------192--------4--------2
3------192--------3--------2
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: what do you want to do exactly ?

Comment: @Blag I was wondering how to get their best(highest) score and have that rank the one that's selected(I probably should have made it more clear)

Comment: maybe try a `GROUP BY(UserID)` with a `MAX(Score)`  to get a `maxScore`

Comment: create a fiddle show expected results

Comment: Ok done, check My answer I think it work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `GROUP BY(UserID)` with a `MAX(Score)` to get a `maxScore` and then rank with it.

(As OP Want every line of user but only the best rank we add an `INNER JOIN`)

```
SELECT TM.`UserID`, TM.`Score`, T3.`rank`
FROM `Users` as TM
INNER JOIN (
        SELECT `UserID`, FIND_IN_SET(
                Max(`Score`), (
                    select GROUP_CONCAT(
                        DISTINCT `Score`
                        order by `Score` DESC
                    )
                    From (
                        select MAX(`Score`) as `Score`
                        FROM `Users` as T0
                        GROUP BY `UserID`
                    ) as T1
                )
            ) as `rank`
        FROM `Users` as T2
        group by `UserID`
    ) as T3
    ON TM.`UserID` = T3.`UserID`
-- If we need to filter or sort, we make it here :
WHERE TM.`UserID` = 192
ORDER BY TM.`Score`
```

Comment: This is the closest one that works so far, but it's only showing the user once(It's not he `DISTICT` clause) I've tried to figure out how, but I can't.(I'm not good in this advanced SQL)

Comment: why you want it more than once ? cause it's not "normal" either you keep the best score and rank or you get the rank for every score... ; BTW, it's the 1st `MAX` and last `GROUP BY` who do this trick

Comment: I want the others because there's more information inside the rows. I just didn't include it for sake of simplicity.

Comment: @MakerModelLua ok, I edit my post, try this one, I don't test it as I've droped my test table

Comment: @MakerModelLua it may not be the most efficient way, but As I don't exactly know what you want I'll not try to improve it (as you can see, there is many `SELECT`, so many sub-query, and this kind of things is slow~~)

Comment: Thanks @Blarg, it works! Just one more thing, I can't figure out where to put the `WHERE` Clause or `ORDER` Clause(I feel like a noob)

Comment: Ah, I needed `TM.UserID` (it said `UserID` was ambiguous) Thanks for all your help :)

Comment: @MakerModelLua yes you need to be specific when dealing with join table, If fact I should have specified every field with the aliased (`AS x`)  table in each sub query, but I think it work like this, no ? (& don't forget to +1 the answer)

Comment: extra UserID ? where ?

Comment: [First part of query](http://puu.sh/llUst.png) then most of the arbitrary data.  [Then the last part](http://puu.sh/llUrA.png)

Comment: I would +1 but I need more rep (I've used it before but I just made this account). I'll +1 once I get 15 rep

Comment: @MakerModelLua take a look at you first `SELECT`, I think you use a `*`, if yes, then it'll bring you back the UserID from the `JOIN` ; use `SELECT TM.*, T3.rank` to get just the rank

Comment: Ya I'm using a `*` for the first select. I need it because I wish to get all the fields for an API. Is there an easier way or do i need to specify all the columns?

Comment: As I said, use : `SELECT T3.rank, TM.*` it will get you every field of `TM` as you use a `*`, and only `rank` for the filter table T3

Comment: Thanks! You've been a big help :)

Comment: You're welcome, your question was a really funny one ; dat' sql request~ ;)

Comment: I've been using this for a while and it's been working great up until now. For some reason any user's rank above 188 becomes 0 [picture](http://puu.sh/lwkIH.png)

Comment: @MakerModelLua ah yes, sorry, forgot this f*** thing : by [default, groupconcat is truncate at 1024](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat), change the [group_concat_max_len MySql var](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len) to an upper length, I think it'll solve your problem ;)

Comment: @MakerModelLua if it don't solve your problem, make a http://sqlfiddle.com/ with data to reproduce, I'll need to play a bit with it to find where is the bug

Comment: I tried SET group_concat_max_len=18446744073709551615; at the beginning, but it didn't change anything. I don't have super privileges, so i can't set global. And I tried modify my.cnf but i think I would need to reboot the db(which I can't do)

Comment: @MakerModelLua ok, make a sqlfiddle please

Comment: @MakerModelLua could you reproduce your bug on sqlFiddle ? (do you get the same bug)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
SET @rank=0;
SELECT *, @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank
FROM Users
WHERE UserID = 100
ORDER BY Score DESC
```

Comment: The problem with that is it ranks null and it will only rank the selected, where as the one I'm currently using ranks everybody, but runs into the individual rank problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can count every user with less score:

```
SELECT u.ID, u.UserID u.Score, 1 + COUNT(*) as Rank -- 1 + count every user with less score
FROM Users u
JOIN Users loser
  ON loser.Score < u.score -- join with every user having less score
GROUP BY u.ID, u.UserID, u.Score
ORDER BY Rank
```

Comment: you can't group by the score like that... need a MAX to get the best one

Comment: you're right. In best case i would get the same result as the OP (if i fix other mistakes :-))

Comment: yes ;) (and if you look at my final version, it's a f*** big baby to get what OP want u_u )